# Adding Minutes to Pandas DatetimeIndex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an index that contain dates.

```
DatetimeIndex(['2004-01-02', '2004-01-05', '2004-01-06', '2004-01-07',
           '2004-01-08', '2004-01-09', '2004-01-12', '2004-01-13',
           '2004-01-14', '2004-01-15',
           ...
           '2015-12-17', '2015-12-18', '2015-12-21', '2015-12-22',
           '2015-12-23', '2015-12-24', '2015-12-28', '2015-12-29',
           '2015-12-30', '2015-12-31'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=3021, freq=None)
```

Now for each day I would like to generate every minute (24*60=1440 minutes) within each day and make an index with all days and minutes.

The result should look like:

```
['2004-01-02 00:00:00', '2004-01-02 00:01:00', ..., '2004-01-02 23:59:00',
 '2004-01-03 00:00:00', '2004-01-03 00:01:00', ..., '2004-01-03 23:59:00',
 ...
 '2015-12-31 00:00:00', '2015-12-31 00:01:00', ..., '2015-12-31 23:59:00']
```

Is there a smart trick for this?

Comment: how should look your final `DatetimeIndex` ?

Comment: Some of your dates differ in 3 days `'2004-01-02', '2004-01-05'` . Is that intentional?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes. Holidays removed. I just would like to generate for these days. Otherwise it would have been very easy with range.

Comment: I think I can do with join.

Comment: Is it standalone index or it's an index of dataframe?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have a list of timestamps, if that's going to make things easier. It really doesn't matter. I can take it out, put back it, whatever.

Comment: I have a solution for your issue, but I need you to post the initial actual dataset (you mentioned about list of timestamps) I need to be assured that working with correct input data

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I solved it the old fashioned way. Ran a for loop, slow but surprise free.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `.asfreq()` here:

```
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> days = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', days=10)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(len(days))), index=days)
>>> df.asfreq('min')                                                                                                                                     
                       0
2018-01-01 00:00:00  0.0
2018-01-01 00:01:00  NaN
2018-01-01 00:02:00  NaN
2018-01-01 00:03:00  NaN
2018-01-01 00:04:00  NaN
2018-01-01 00:05:00  NaN
2018-01-01 00:06:00  NaN
# ...

>>> df.shape                                                                                                                                             
(10, 1)

>>> df.asfreq('min').shape                                                                                                                               
(12961, 1)
```

If that doesn't work for some reason, you might also want to have a look into [`pd.MultiIndex.from_product()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object); then `pd.to_datetime()` on the concatenated result.